# Unable to send email array in mandrill JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, mandrill

Hi I have a form which the user inputs a message and sends it to multiple recipients. I am using Mandrill as my email client and the script is as follows

```
function sendMail() {

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var array = email.split(',');
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var msg = $("#msg").val();


$.ajax({

  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
  data: {
    'key': 'xxxxxxx',
    'message': {
      'from_email': 'xxx@xxx.com',
      'to': [
          {
            'email': email,

            'type': 'to'
          }
        ],
      'autotext': 'true',
      'subject': 'Hello world ' + name,
      'html': msg + '<br> <br> <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzmi0gssmwn/image/upload/v1434831725/wpeqmuld5gzdplf7kzcw.jpg" width:320px;height:auto/>'
    }
  }
 }).done(function(response) {
        alert('Your message has been sent. Thank you!'); // show success message
        $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        alert('Error sending message.');
    });
  }

</script>
```

When I input one email address the message gets successfully sent and received in the inbox. But when I submit with multiple addresses, I get a response that the message has been sent, but when I looked at the logs it states

```
[{"email":"xxxx@xxx.xxx, xxxx@xxx.xxx","status":"invalid","_id":"c045cbffbd0c4c5ab5581f5edaff2007","reject_reason":null}]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue or understand whats going wrong ? Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just use mandrill API through js SDK

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mandrill.min.js"></script>
```

It can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-js/src/ae244a4d28f7f51327f6982005d4283d5f329b35/mandrill.min.js?at=master).

```
var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('api key');

function sendTheMail(){
    m.messages.send({
        "message": {
            "from_email": "xx@xx.com",
            "from_name": "test",
            "to":[{"email": "xx@x.com", "name": "someone's_name"}],
            "subject": "subj",
            "text": "msg" 
        }
    });
}
```

Shouldn't you be doing this on server, however, since this will basically show your API to public, and once it's public even for millisecond a bot will have it saved forever.

Comment: The issue is that i am unable to successfully send the emails when multiple recipients are entered. It works fine when a single email address is entered

Comment: Hi sorry but your solution doesn't explain how to handle the multiple recipients. How do i pharse the  var array = email.split(',');  and add it to the json object.

Comment: What is the value of email before you split post an example

Comment: xxx@email.com, xxx@gmail.com,xxx@yahoo.com

Comment: `var arr =[]; email.split(',').forEach(function(k){ arr.push ( {email:k}); });` put arr to "to":